# RabbitMQ: Limiting consumer prefetch across multiple connections

Tags: rabbitmq

I have two processes on two different servers connecting to RabbitMQ and consuming messages from the same queues (for active/active HA).  Is it possible to ensure that a maximum *total* of one message in a queue is unacked at a given point in time, across two connections?

Combining the "exclusive" flag with basic.qos(1) would ensure that a maximum of one message in a queue is unacked at a given point in time, but would have only one process consuming.

Is there a way to have a consumer prefetch limit (e.g. basic.qos(1)) apply as a total across all connections while still having all connections able to consume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Please see the [documentation for the `global` flag](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html).